# Combination of grouped values in SAS

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I am trying to find the various combinations only in the cases where the records in the below dataset only differ by the column type. So for example: the first three rows only differ by the column type

Given Dataset

```
ins_id    ins_number   type
1234      1234-1234-1  AU
1234      1234-1234-1  HM
1234      1234-1234-1  RE
567       567-567-12   TL
567       567-567-13   TL
9101      9101-1234-1  AU
9101      9101-1234-1  TX
9101      9101-1234-1  CN
8854      8854-1234-1  TX
8854      8854-1234-1  GB
8854      8854-1234-1  RE
8854      8854-1234-2  RX

Expected Output:
combination  count
AU,HM,RE     1
AU,TX,CN     1
TX,GB,RE     1
```

I tried writing the query but I am not getting the desired output, please help:

```
proc sql;create table tst as select cp.type, 
       count(distinct ins_id)
from (select distinct fac_prod_typ from dataset3a) cp cross join
     (select distinct ins_number from dataset3a) pes left join
     dataset3a
     on dataset3a.type = cp.type and
        dataset3a.ins_number = pes.ins_number
group by cp.type, pes.ins_number;quit;
```

Comment: A data step would be much easier here, using BY group processing. Is that an option here?

Comment: Yes, anything as long as it's the correct output.

Comment: If among the different types within a group there is a repeated type do you want to how many times the type occurred ? (for example an id with 6 records, 3 types and some repeats could be summarized as `AU,HM(3),RE(2)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use FIRST/LAST logic is nice here.
To get the counts, run a PROC FREQ on the final output and this would also allow you to identify the ins_id for the mixes as well.

```
data have;
informat ins_id $8. ins_number $25. type $2.;
input ins_id  $  ins_number $  type $;
cards;
1234      1234-1234-1  AU
1234      1234-1234-1  HM
1234      1234-1234-1  RE
567       567-567-12   TL
567       567-567-13   TL
9101      9101-1234-1  AU
9101      9101-1234-1  TX
9101      9101-1234-1  CN
8854      8854-1234-1  TX
8854      8854-1234-1  GB
8854      8854-1234-1  RE
;;;;

data want;
set have;
by ins_id ins_number type notsorted;
retain combo;
length combo $256.;
if first.ins_number then call missing(combo);

if first.type then combo = catx(", ", combo, type);

if last.ins_number and countw(combo)>1 then output;

run;
```

Comment: Hi Reeza, it doesn't work if we add one more row as I have done to my original post. That test case fails. So basically, for 8854, there should be TX, GB, RE and not RX

Comment: So you only want the first three? By order or is RX excluded for some other reason?

Comment: Assuming INS_NUMBER is the key, just change your FIRST/LAST to refer to the last variable that uniquely identifies a grouping.

Answer (score 2):

You will want to sort the data to ensure the types list is consistent over all ids.
A DOW loop over a `SET...; BY...;` will output one types list per group.
The last step is using Proc FREQ to count the number of ids for each types list.

Example:

```
data have;
informat ins_id $8. ins_number $25. type $2.;
input ins_id  $  ins_number $  type $;
cards;
1234      1234-1234-1  AU
1234      1234-1234-1  HM
1234      1234-1234-1  RE
567       567-567-12   TL
567       567-567-13   TL
9101      9101-1234-1  AU
9101      9101-1234-1  TX
9101      9101-1234-1  CN
8854      8854-1234-1  TX
8854      8854-1234-1  GB
8854      8854-1234-1  RE
8854      8854-1234-2  RX
;

/* force specific ordering of type within group id and number */
/* necessary for proper frequency counting */
/* if sequence of types IS important do not sort and data step by ... NOTSORTED */

proc sort data=have;
  by ins_id ins_number type;
run;

data types(keep=types);
  length types $200;
  do until (last.ins_number);
    set have;
    by ins_id ins_number;
    if indexw(types, type) = 0 then types = catx(',',types,type);
  end;
  if index(types,',') then output;
run;

proc freq noprint data=types;
  table types / out=types_counts(keep=types count) ;
run;
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Richard, it doesn't work if we add one more row as I have done to my original post. That test case fails. So basically, for 8854, there should be TX, GB, RE and not RX

Comment: I see.  The `BY` group needs to be the two variables `INS_ID INS_NUMBER`. Will fix.

Comment: Yup, that worked. You are awesome, thanks